# How to find the desired element in the array and check whether it has a value or not?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a big array like this:

```
"twitter_link" => "http://twitter.com"
"twitter_text" => "text"
"youtube_link" => ""
"youtube_text" => ""
"snapchat_link" => "http://twitter.com"
"snapchat_text" => "text"
"linkedin_link" => ""
"linkedin_text" => ""
```

In this array, I need to find all all *_link keys and check if the value is set, then add all the keys where there is a value to another array

Comment: So iterate over array, it's simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to recommend you to read the following docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#available-methods, this may help you to find a multiple ways to iterate and alter an array if you don't think the array_* methods from php are enough for your needs! :D

Answering your question, what you need here is the knowledge of:

1. [`preg_match(...)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) function
2. [`array_filter(...)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function using the flag: ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH

You simply have to do the following:

```php
$result = array_filter($links, fn($v, $k) => ($v !== "" && preg_match("/(_link)+$/i", $k)), ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH)
```

And voilá, but what's the explanation? Simply...

1. Filter will use key and value for filtering by passing the flag `ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH` as third element on `array_filter()` method.
2. On the filtering process, the `$v` (or value) shouldn't be empty.
3. Also on the filtering process, the `$k` (or key) should have a `_filter` at the end of the string.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will read the documentation)